# How does Haskell evaluate the Fibonacci function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fibonacci, reduction

I am currently looking at this function in Haskell which returns the Fibonacci number at position `n`

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Now, it compiles, returns the correct result and everything... but I don't see how Haskell evaluates this function.

Doesn't Haskell always look for a suitable definition and then apply that definition until it cannot anymore (e.g. reached base case)?

In that case, this is what I came up with. For instance, evaluating `fib 3`

```
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
fib 3 = fib (3-1) + fib (3-2)
fib 3 = fib ((3-1)-1) + fib ((3-1)-2) + fib ((3-2)-1) + fib ((3-2)-2)
fib 3 = fib (((3-1)-1)-1) + fib (((3-1)-1)-2) +
        fib (((3-1)-2)-1) + fib (((3-1)-2)-2) + 
        fib (((3-2)-1)-1) + fib (((3-2)-1)-2) + 
        fib (((3-2)-2)-1) + fib (((3-2)-2)-2)
...
```

This could go on forever without giving an actual result. However, Haskell returns a result. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the equations in the definition does matter.

The part

```
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

gets applied only when the previous lines *do not apply*. That is, only when `n` is not `0` nor `1`. Because of this, the step

```
fib 3 = fib (3-1) + fib (3-2)
fib 3 = fib ((3-1)-1) + fib ((3-1)-2) + fib ((3-2)-1) + fib ((3-2)-2)
```

is wrong: `fib (3-2)` is `fib 1 = 1`, and not `fib ((3-2)-1) + fib ((3-2)-2)`.

Another way to look at is is as follows.
The whole 3-lines definition can be equivalently expressed using `case` as

```
fib n = case n of
        0 -> 0
        1 -> 1
        m -> fib (m-1) + fib (m-2)
```

Comment: thanks, the part `gets applied only when the previous lines do not apply` made it clear to me